# Trouble converting Values in Column into Row Names of Data Frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe, r-rownames

I am trying to convert the first column of a data frame as Row names.

It works fine but the names of the data frame format changes!

It changes from like `100-21-0` to `X100.21.0`

First column is Character values: Code, CBT, DQY, DQX etc.
and the names (or the first row?) of the data frame (double) like: Code, 100-21-0, 1002-84-2, 100-47-0 etc.

| Code | 100-21-0 |
| --- | --- |
| CBT | 0 |
| DQY | 1 |

I am using the code similar to:

```r
newdataframe <- data.frame(dataframe, row.names = 1)
```

It works fine but the names of the data frame change from 100-21-0, 1002-84-2, 100-47-0 to X100.21.0, X1002.84.2, X100.47.0 !!!

I am confused why? Can anyone help on this?

Comment: Could you provide the output of `dput(data)`?

Comment: Use check.names = FALSE: `newdataframe <- data.frame(dataframe, row.names = 1,  check.names=FALSE)`

Comment: It's like--> structure(list(X100.21.0 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0,.............    class = "data.frame", row.names = c("CBT", "DQX", 
"DQY",.......     ))